# query to count the similar values for each column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Please could you help to get the query for the below table

```
╔══════════════╗
║ A  B   C   D ║
╠══════════════╣
║ N  E   1  -5 ║
║ N  N   4  -3 ║
║ N  -4  6   E ║
║ 3  E   E  -8 ║
║ 1  N   N   N ║
╚══════════════╝
```

I need the output as below

```
╔═════════════════════════════════╗
║    N    E     NegativeValues    ║
╠═════════════════════════════════╣
║ A  3    0     0                 ║
║ B  2    2     1                 ║
║ C  1    1     0                 ║
║ D  1    1     3                 ║
╚═════════════════════════════════╝
```

i need to get the count for N and E and negative values for all the columns. Please help. Thanks in advance

**Update**
Here N is NULL and E starts with the string "-1E+70"

Comment: What server do you use MS SQL-Server or Oracle?

Comment: Hi Igor, i am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: @Reyaz : What have you tried ?

Comment: @RaviSingh: I tried with just grouping the values for N and E for one column and i am stuck with grouping the negative values. But i need the output as i mentioned above which i am not sure how to get. And i am new to sql. Please help

Comment: If you don't want to use pivote/ unpivote then see my solution. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 7):

Try un-pivoting and then conditionally counting the rows.
Something like this:

```
SELECT ABC, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN VALS = 'n' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) n, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN VALS = 'e' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) E, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN LEFT(VALS, 1) = '-' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) NegativeValues 
FROM   TABLE1 
       UNPIVOT (VALS 
               FOR ABC IN ([A], 
                           [B], 
                           [C], 
                           [D]))t 
GROUP  BY ABC
```

Take a look at a working example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/399554/5).
Good Luck!

---

Taking into account that the 'n' value is actually NULL and that the `UNPIVOT` function drops NULL values and that the 'e' value is actually '-1e',  here is an updated version of the query:

```
SELECT ABC, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN VALS = 'NULL' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) n, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN VALS = '-1e' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) E, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN LEFT(VALS, 1) = '-' 
                  AND Charindex('e', VALS) = 0 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) NegativeValues 
FROM   (SELECT Isnull(A, 'NULL')A, 
               Isnull(B, 'NULL')B, 
               Isnull(C, 'NULL')C, 
               Isnull(D, 'NULL')D 
        FROM   TABLE1)T 
       UNPIVOT (VALS 
               FOR ABC IN ([A], 
                           [B], 
                           [C], 
                           [D]))t 
GROUP  BY ABC
```

And here is an updated link to the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/762e8/2).

---

**Edit**
With the new info that -1e are actually scientific numbers and that all the fields are float types, here is my updated solution (hopefully final):

```
SELECT ABC, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN VALS = 'NULL' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) n, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN VALS LIKE '-1e+070%' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) E, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN LEFT(VALS, 1) = '-' 
                  AND Charindex('e', VALS) = 0 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) NegativeValues 
FROM   (SELECT Isnull(Cast(A AS VARCHAR(10)), 'NULL')A, 
               Isnull(Cast(B AS VARCHAR(10)), 'NULL')B, 
               Isnull(Cast(C AS VARCHAR(10)), 'NULL')C, 
               Isnull(Cast(D AS VARCHAR(10)), 'NULL')D 
        FROM   TABLE1)T 
       UNPIVOT (VALS 
               FOR ABC IN ([A], 
                           [B], 
                           [C], 
                           [D]))t 
GROUP  BY ABC
```

And of course a new link to [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30797/5).

Comment: @Devart: Same for you! :)

Comment: @Gidil: Thanks for the query, actually N is NULL and E is some string in my case. I tried to replace but i am not getting the number of nulls for the column. please could you help?

Comment: Sure! I assume you tried to replace the NULL part, right? You should have any problem with E. Let me know if I'm wrong ;-)

Comment: Yes, i replace N with NULL and E starts with "-1E" in my case. "-1E" conflicts with the negative values checking i think. Please could you rewrite the query now. thanks

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the -1e

Comment: Here's the update. Please let me know if it helps you or any more changes need to be made. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the update Gidil, i tried the query but i am getting the error "Error converting data type varchar to float." All the columns i have in the table are float

Comment: is the value -1e or is that a scientific notification?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34673/discussion-between-gidil-and-reyaz)

Comment: its an scientific notification

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (A CHAR(2), B CHAR(2), C CHAR(2), D CHAR(2))

INSERT INTO @temp (A, B, C, D)
VALUES 
    (NULL, 'E'  , '1', '-5'),
    (NULL, NULL  , '4', '-3'),
    (NULL, '-4' , '6', 'E'),
    ('3', 'E'  , 'E', '-8'),
    ('1', NULL  , NULL, NULL)

SELECT 
      Code
    , N = COUNT(CASE WHEN Value = '' THEN 1 END)
    , E = COUNT(CASE WHEN Value LIKE '%[A-Z]%' THEN 1 END)
    , NegativeValues = COUNT(CASE WHEN LEFT(Value, 1) = '-' THEN 1 END)
FROM (
    SELECT 
          A = ISNULL(A, '')
        , B = ISNULL(B, '')
        , C = ISNULL(C, '')
        , D = ISNULL(D, '')
    FROM @temp
) t
UNPIVOT 
(
    Value FOR Code IN (A, B, C, D)
) unpvt
GROUP BY Code
```

Comment: Thanks for the query, but here N is NULL and E is 'string' . could you please rewrite the query now. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the query, but if i execute this i am getting wrong output for the negative values ( the output now is like: for negative values = error values which it starts with "-1E+30" + actual negative values). Please help

Answer (score 1):

For a more generic solution you can refer the following query:

```
  SELECT "A", 
       Sum(N) N, 
       Sum(E) E, 
       Sum(M) "Negative" 
FROM   (SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN A = "N" THEN Count(A) 
                 ELSE 0 
               END N, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN A = "E" THEN Count(A) 
                 ELSE 0 
               END E, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN A LIKE "%-%" THEN Count(A) 
                 ELSE 0 
               END "M" 
        FROM   #TAB2 
        GROUP  BY A) aa 
UNION 
SELECT "B", 
       Sum(N) N, 
       Sum(E) E, 
       Sum(M) "Negative" 
FROM   (SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN B = "N" THEN Count(B) 
                 ELSE 0 
               END N, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN B = "E" THEN Count(B) 
                 ELSE 0 
               END E, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN B LIKE "%-%" THEN Count(B) 
                 ELSE 0 
               END "M" 
        FROM   #TAB2 
        GROUP  BY B) bb 
UNION 
SELECT "C", 
       Sum(N) N, 
       Sum(E) E, 
       Sum(M) "Negative" 
FROM   (SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN C = "N" THEN Count(A) 
                 ELSE 0 
               END N, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN C = "E" THEN Count(A) 
                 ELSE 0 
               END E, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN C LIKE "%-%" THEN Count(C) 
                 ELSE 0 
               END "M" 
        FROM   #TAB2 
        GROUP  BY C) cc 
UNION 
SELECT "D", 
       Sum(N) N, 
       Sum(E) E, 
       Sum(M) "Negative" 
FROM   (SELECT CASE 
                 WHEN D = "N" THEN Count(D) 
                 ELSE 0 
               END N, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN D = "E" THEN Count(D) 
                 ELSE 0 
               END E, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN D LIKE "%-%" THEN Count(D) 
                 ELSE 0 
               END "M" 
        FROM   #TAB2 
        GROUP  BY D) dd
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If you have only four columns then you can try this solution.
```

**[Here is SQLFiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b1f56/14)**

**Below is the query which you can try :**

```
select 'A' as ColumnName,
       (select count(*) 
          from Table1
         where A = 'N') as N,
       (select count(*) 
          from Table1
         where A = 'E') as E,
       (select count(*) 
          from Table1
         where substring(A,1,1) = '-') as Negative
union
select 'B' as ColumnName,
       (select count(*) 
          from Table1
         where B = 'N') as N,
       (select count(*) 
          from Table1
         where B = 'E') as E,
       (select count(*) 
          from Table1
         where substring(B,1,1) = '-') as Negative
union
select 'C' as ColumnName,
       (select count(*) 
          from Table1
         where C = 'N') as N,
       (select count(*) 
          from Table1
         where C = 'E') as E,
       (select count(*) 
          from Table1
         where substring(C,1,1) = '-') as Negative
union
select 'D' as ColumnName,
       (select count(*) 
          from Table1
         where D = 'N') as N,
       (select count(*) 
          from Table1
         where D = 'E') as E,
       (select count(*) 
          from Table1
         where substring(D,1,1) = '-') as Negative
```